# How to read file from the command line on Mac terminal for Python

Tags: python, macos, pycharm

How would I read a file ( .in format) and apply it to my .py Python program?

For example, my python code is titled as *Add_4.py* :

```
import sys
main():
    num = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
    final_output = num + 4
    print(final_output)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the text file would be titled *Numbers.in*:

```
5
18
-3
```

I believe I have to use the '<' symbol within the terminal, and I know that I have to trace the location of my files, but I am brand new to Python and Coding in general so I am having a hard time figuring this out. This format is being used for my class btw! Sorry if anything is confusing.

Comment: you want to read and print number+4 for numbers in each line of a ".in" file ? from command prompt ? is that right ?

Comment: @SANGEETHSUBRAMONIAM yes! I realized I wrote the code completely wrong and it would not run correctly, but what you asked is what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have file `add4.py`, content:

```py
import sys
def main():
    num = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
    final_output = num + 4
    print(final_output)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and you have plaintext file `Numbers.in`, content:

```
5
18
-3
```

You can pipe OR redirect content of `Numbers.in` to `add4.py` by using `|` (pipe) or by using `<` (read stdin from file)

example 1:

```
$ cat Numbers.in | python add4.py
9
```

example 2:

```
$ python add4.py < Numbers.in
9
```

Do note that because of the way your python code is written, only first line is read (number `5`) and then added with `4` to become `9`.

---

If you want to read multiple lines and expect output like

```
9
22
1
```

then you should use `readlines` rather than `readline`.

File `add4all.py`, content:

```
import sys
def main():
    lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
    for num in lines:
        final_output = int(num) + 4
        print(final_output)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then the result is:

```
$ python add4all.py < Numbers.in 
9
22
1
```